# Une méthode traditionnelle pour FLE

Tags: grammaire

Je cherche une **méthode traditionnelle pour apprendre le français** en tant que langue étrangère. Une méthode où l'on apprendrait la grammaire en même temps que le vocabulaire, de telle sorte que l'on puisse maîtriser la grammaire parfaitement (grammaire simple j'entends, pas forcément toutes ses spécificités).
J'exclue les méthodes type "Assimil" qui vous jettent directement tous les mots à la figure, et dont on ressort avec une vague idée de la langue sans être capable de formuler une phrase correcte. (ces méthodes ne conviennent pas à tous)

En réalité, je cherche exactement le genre de méthode que nous avions lorsque nous étions au primaire, avec des tableaux de grammaire, des tests à trous, des exercices de type Bescherelle etc... (grammaire des années 50-60 qui sont parfois encore utilisées dans certaines écoles primaires)
J'ai beaucoup cherché sur internet, et aussi dans les bibliothèques, mais rien trouvé. Des idées ? des ressources peut-être ?
J'effectue cette recherche pour un ami étranger dont la langue est assez éloigné des langues latines et plus généralement, des langues européennes, c'est pourquoi j'insiste sur l'aspect grammatical.

Comment: Votre ami parle-t-i anglais ou non ?

Comment: Oui, il parle anglais, et aussi italien. Cependant, c'est quand nous parlons italien ensemble que je repère de lourdes fautes de grammaire (par rapport aux langues latines)

Comment: Quant aux anciens manuels veuillez voir ici https://manuelsanciens.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 3):

The Alliance Française's entire mission is to teach French or FLE. Here is an example of their introductory offerings. This is merely an example. Notice how complete it is and how well laid out it is.

> **FRANÇAIS | TRAVEL & TALK - NIVEAUX A1 À B2 Formation en ligne Edited by Toutapprendre - Travel & Talk Ce cours de Français Langue
> Etrangère, incluant 3 niveaux de faux débutant à perfectionnement,
> s'adresse aux adultes étrangers salariés ou en recherche d'emploi.**
>
> Objectif : L'objectif général de cette méthode d'apprentissage du
> Français Langue Etrangère (FLE) en ligne est que vous puissiez
> communiquer naturellement dans les diverses situations de la vie
> personnelle et professionnelle en France. Pour cela, cette méthode
> pour apprendre le Français, développée par Travel & Talk, vous
> entraînera à : La compréhension orale La compréhension écrite La
> production orale (via des outils d'enregistrements de sa voix) La
> production écrite Le contenu de ce cours de Français Langue Etrangère
> (FLE) en ligne est organisé autour des thèmes de la vie quotidienne.
> Des rencontres avec des Français, dès le début de la méthode,
> permettent de créer les dialogues.
>
> Séquences d'apprentissage Chacune des thématiques développées dans ce
> cours de Français Langue Etrangère contient 9 séquences
> d'apprentissage réparties de manière égale. **La méthode de Français
> Langue Etrangère comprend environ 80 séquences d'apprentissage, chaque
> séquence d'apprentissage est destinée à apprendre un savoir-faire
> («Apprendre à...») au travers d'un point de grammaire et d'un point de
> vocabulaire.**
>
> Évaluation Cette méthode d'apprentissage du Français Langue Etrangère
> contient de nombreux tests (1 test à la fin de chaque thématique).
>
> Parcours
> **Dans cette méthode de Français Langue Etrangère en ligne, la difficulté sera progressive au sein de chaque thématique et se
> développera sur les 3 niveaux**. Vous pourrez choisir de travailler
> une thématique dans sa totalité ou bien de les parcourir toutes en
> suivant la piste d'un niveau. Un carnet de bord en ligne enregistrera
> les séquences de Français réalisées et en cours de réalisation.
>
> Niveau atteint : **B1 du Cadre européen des Langues.**

[Alliance Française](https://www.culturetheque.com/US/doc/TOUTAPPRENDRE/6136/francais-travel-talk-niveaux-a1-a-b2) [bolding mine]

Here is the general link for their library:
[Library](http://fiaf.org/library/)

Here is their Culturethèque: [FIAF](http://fiaf.org/library/culturetheque/). Yes, you have to become a member but it's worth it.

Depending on where you live, you can also go to an Alliance Francaise. They are located in 120 countries. It is a great institution. You can see French movies at their sites, attend cultural events, and take out books, too. They also have stuff for kids.

Here is the description of the Fondation and its mission around the world:
[Fondation des alliances françaises](https://www.fondation-alliancefr.org/)

Answer (score 2):

The following is relevant if either you or friend speaks English. They are some guidelines for learning French from scratch.

First of all Internet offers a plethora of options. To name but a few (all free):

- [BBC courses](https://www.bbc.co.uk/languages/french/index.shtml)
- [LawlessFrench](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/)
- [ToLearnFrench](https://www.tolearnfrench.com/)

They provide almost everything a beginner should know.

There are many great grammar books for beginners and Amazon is a good place to find used ones at affordable prices. Personally, I highly recommend the book **Easy French Step-by-Step**, a best seller for anglophone learners of French, which has the advantage of a very reasonable price. The only drawback I see, is the lack of an accompanied CD for the pronunciation but one can certainly deal with it by watching French tutorial videos in YouTube.  Of course the aforementioned online courses also contain relevant material.

There are online dictionaries, but it is a good practice to have always available a hard copy.

One can find a glossary of the basic grammatical terminology (accusative, dative, personal pronouns and the like) usually in the form of an appendix in almost every grammar book for learning French. The aforementioned appendices are most often accompanied by the French counterparts. I.e. Imperfect=Imparfait, Perfect=Passé Composé, Pluperfect=Plus-que-parfait, Past Historic=Passé Simple, Accusative/Dative=Complément d'Object Direct/Indirect, etc.

Of course, as always, Internet offers information about almost everything (glossary). But personally being a little archaic, I prefer the hard copies. Thus, I suggest also a French Reference Grammar like that of H. Ferrar (Cambridge University Press) which has the advantage of being irresistibly...cheap (used copy).

See also the discussion below

[Please suggest any French grammar books](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30622/please-suggest-any-french-grammar-books)

[Recommended grammar textbook for self-study](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7804/recommended-grammar-textbook-for-self-study)

[Resources to verify French words, expressions, usage, grammar](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24262/resources-to-verify-french-words-expressions-usage-grammar?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. The Easy French Step by Step seems to be rather good for beginners with good grammar points. I will have a look on the Ferrar's grammar also